Sending Passports to a Canada Visa Application Center in Another Country
My parents, who are Turkish citizens, applied for a visitor visa to Canada several months ago while in Turkey. As part of the application process, they provided their biometric data. They are currently visiting me in Seattle, USA as tourists and have just received an email stating that their visa has been approved and they need to send their Turkish passports within 30 days for stamping.
However, I am hesitant to send their passports due to concerns about the timing of their return flight to Turkey, which is in five weeks. If their passports do not arrive back in time, they will be unable to return home. Additionally, I would like them to receive their Canada visa as soon as possible so we can visit Vancouver during their stay.
I have noticed that there is a Canada Visa Application Center (VAC) in Los Angeles, and I believe sending their passports there may be the safest and fastest option. Can anyone confirm if it is possible to send a passport to a Canada VAC located in another country, even if it is not related to the applicant's country of origin or original application center?

Where are they asking you to send the passports to?  To a VAC in Turkey?

The approval letter doesn't specify that. The "Where to submit your passport" website says "To find out where to send your passport, look for YOUR country or territory in the list below." though https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/account/where-submit-passport.html

I know for Italy and USA they only allow applications where the applicant resides, not where one is visiting.

I reached out to LA VAC via email first. They replied in 1hr but the response felt automated and didn't give me the peace of mind. Then I reached out using the live chat option and got the confirmation from the agent.
Followed the steps explained in this reddit post to send passports. The whole process was super quick and received the passports back in 4 days.

Please describe the steps here rather than point to a post on an other site which may disappear.
